# Sorting layers and attributes displayed in ArcMap Create Features window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing

At ArcMap (advanced) 10.3.1, items displayed in the Create Features window are sorted alphabetically.

How can I re-sort them so that they match the Table of Contents display order?

A search through the Arc help documents did not discuss this issue...

[image]

Comment: It is only possible to sort asc or desc alphabetically/numerically based on the symbol attribute value.  What is the point of sorting them the same as TOC?

Comment: Consistency is the reason to sort them.  The TOC layers are sorted in their correct screen display order.  Further, within each TOC layer, attributes are sorted according to the client's requirements.  We're finding that users are getting disoriented when they start an editing session because the Create Features window items are sorted differently than the TOC.  I have to agree with the client... the software should work for them rather than forcing them to adapt to the software.  In that spirit one might ask: what's the point of NOT having the Create Features window match the TOC?

Comment: It sounds like a matter of opinion and a software/software user issue, not a GIS issue.  You should contact ESRI or post on an esri support forum.

Comment: This is a feature request for ESRI.  I agree with you that you should be able to control how it is sorted.  I just don't think this is the right forum to ask this question as it is specifically about ESRI arcmap software behaviour, not GIS.  Maybe look at user training until you can get a response from ESRI or look at a different workflow.  I don't really understand how your users are choosing the wrong feature to create when it clearly states what each symbol is referencing in the create features box.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should investigate [Grouping feature templates in the Create Features window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/grouping-feature-templates-in-the-create-features-window.htm):

> Grouping or sorting feature templates by type, layer, or frequency of
>   use makes it easier for you to find the template you want in the
>   Create Features window.

If you need more control then I think this should be or become the subject of an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).

Comment: Great idea, but unfortunately none of the grouping or sorting options allows you to match the TOC ordering.  I'll submit it as an idea.